# Angular resources doesn't fill scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I have a simple controller with a Service as dependency. I'm trying to fill the scope once the promise of the `resource` is resolved. When i `console.log()` the scope it show me correctly the scope with the data, but my ng-repeat doesn't work. Also I'm using the angular extension of `chrome` and on that scope `(posts)` doesn't show any data. What i'm missing?

Controller:

```
function TimelineController($scope,TimelineService)
    {
        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.getPosts = function(wall_type,wall_id) {
            TimelineService.getPosts(wall_type,wall_id).$promise.then(function(result){
                $scope.posts = result.response;
                console.log($scope.posts); // it show correctly the data on console
            });
        }
    }
```

Service

```
function TimelineService($resource) {

        var resource = $resource('/timeline/:postId',
            {postId:"@id"}
        );

        return {
            getPosts: function(entity,id)
            {
                // /timeline?entity=user&id=3 (example url)
                return resource.get({entity:entity,id:id});
            }
        }
    };
```

The response from the server is:

```
{success:true, response:[...]}
```

**Edit:**

I'm using a directive to display the template with in `ng-repeat`:

```
function timeline() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                type: '@',
                ids: '@',
                postime: '&'
            },
            templateUrl:"/js/templates/timeline/post-tmpl.html"
        }
};
```

So in my view:

```
<div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="TimelineController">
 <timeline type="user" ids="8" postime="getPosts(wall_type,wall_id)"></timeline>
</div>
```

And the short version of my template:

```
<ol class="timeline" ng-init="postime({wall_type:type,wall_id:ids})">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post.poster.fullname}}
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: And where is the view? especially mentioned `ng-repeat`

Comment: Sorry i edit my post

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the data needs to be applied and digested because the service function is not part of the controller scope.

Within your controller, before or after your console.log, run a `$scope.$apply()`.

If the $apply or $digest is already in progress then you can wrap the `$scope.$apply()` with a setTimeout with a delay of 0, or you can wrap it with a `$scope.$evalAsync()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but adding `$scope.$apply()` throw me this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest, but at least now the data show up only on the `angular chrome inspector`

Comment: I edited the answer provide work around options for that problem.

Comment: Thanks a lots, but I found the problem, because for some reason the scope on the controller is not available to the directive, so i had to pass the scope as a new parameter inside of the directive